# Can we always find a normal subgroup isomorphic to a Quotient group?

Tags: group-theory

I'm not very good with English terms of group theory but here is the question :

$$\forall H\trianglelefteq G \rightarrow \exists H' \trianglelefteq G : {G\over H} \approx H'$$

is above statement always true? or should there be some other constraints?

Comment: Consider the additive group of integers.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė what about it? I mean for whatever $\Bbb{Z}_n$ you choose there is always $n\Bbb{Z}$ to satisfy above guess and vise versa, and I honestly can't think of any other subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: @wj32 it's not supposed to, but $n\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb{Z}\over\Bbb{Z}_n}$

Comment: @Gajoo: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not even a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: @Gajoo: $2\Bbb Z$ is normal in $\Bbb Z$, but no subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$: $\Bbb Z$ has no two-element subgroup.

Comment: @wj32 I've just noticed that, but what about the constraints to make that statement true? is M.K.'s suggestion the weakest constraints we can find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. The smallest counterexample can be found in the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$. There $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but every subgroup of order $4$ in $Q_8$ is cyclic.

However, if we assume that $G$ is finite and abelian, then the statement is true.

Comment: Um, the only nontrivial quotient of $S_3$ is of order two, but the order-two subgroups there are nonnormal.

Comment: @Lubin: Ah, you're right, I forgot we wanted a normal subgroup here..

Comment: I think this is still a strong example, because it shows that $G/H$ not only does not have to be isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$, but $G/H$ does not have to be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$ at all (a common mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The symmetric group $S_5$ has exactly three normal subgroups: $\{1\}$, $S_5$ and the alternating group $A_5$, which has index 2 in $S_5$.

Comment: All you really need here is that $A_5$ has index $2$ in $S_5$, since normal subgroups of order $2$ are always central and $S_5$ has trivial center.

Comment: What on earth is there to downvote about this?